# Problem with finding covariance matrix for Iris data in R

Tags: r, covariance-matrix, iris-dataset

I keep getting NAs when trying to find the covariance matrix for the Iris data in R.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dim(iris)
head(iris)

numIris <- iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric)

plot(numIris[1:100,])

Xraw <- numIris[1:1000,]

plot(iris[1:150,-c(5)]) #species name is the 5th column; excluding it here.
Xraw = iris[1:1000,-c(5)] # this excludes the 5th column, which is the species column
#first, to get covariance, we need to subtract the mean from each column

X = scale(Xraw, scale = FALSE)

head(X)

Xs <- scale(Xraw, scale = TRUE)
head(Xs)

covMat  = (t(X)%*%X)/ (nrow(X)-1)
head(covMat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use `cov(numIris)`?

By trying to select 1000 rows of a matrix/data frame with only 150 rows, you end up with 850 rows full of `NA` values (try `tail(Xraw)` to see).  If you set `Xraw <- iris[, -5]` and go from there you get results such that `all.equal(covMat, cov(iris[, -5]))` is `TRUE`.